# How generalize the bicommutant theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.

**Bicommutant theorem** : Let $\mathcal{S}$ be $*$-subset of $B(H)$, then $\mathcal{S}''$ is the strong closure $\overline{\langle \mathcal{S} \rangle}$ of the algebra $\langle \mathcal{S} \rangle$ generated by $\mathcal{S}$  (called the von Neumann algebra generated by $\mathcal{S}$).

- Now if $\mathcal{S}$ is a non-selfadjoint subset of $B(H)$, what can we say about $\mathcal{S}''$ ?
- Is it true that $\overline{\langle \mathcal{S} \rangle} \subset \mathcal{S}''$ ?
- What are the simplest known subsets $\mathcal{S}$ with $\overline{\langle \mathcal{S} \rangle} \subsetneq \mathcal{S}''$ ? Single operator subsets ?

> How generalize the bicommutant theorem ?

Comment: [Laurent W Marcoux](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~lwmarcou/) will make a report abot Non-selfadjoint double commutant theorems on Saturday, August 3, HA4, 11:35–12:05 in Chalmers University in Gothenburg during conference Banach Algebras 2013. You can visit this conference or contact him via e-mail

Comment: When you'll pass through this paper it would be great if you'll post answer to your question

Comment: @julien, it was ok to post that comment. My comment about Big Brother was just a joke

Comment: @Norbert  Ok, so here it is again: [now](http://www.chalmers.se/sv/institutioner/math/forskning/konferenser-pa-MV/banach-algebras/Sidor/Participants.aspx) we know you go by Norbert in conferences as well. Safe travels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note, e.g. by net manipulations, that for any set $\mathcal{S}\subseteq B(H)$, the bicommutant $\mathcal{S}^{''}$ is a wot/sot-closed unital subalgebra of $B(H)$. So we want to consider the wot/sot-closures of the algebra $\langle \mathcal{S}\rangle$ of all polynomials in elements of $\mathcal{S}$. Since $\langle \mathcal{S}\rangle\subseteq \mathcal{S}^{''}$, and since the wot and sot closures of a convex set coincide, we always have
$$
\overline{\langle \mathcal{S}\rangle}^{sot}=\overline{\langle \mathcal{S}\rangle}^{wot}\subseteq \mathcal{S}^{''}.
$$
The bicommutant property is when the equality holds. I will only consider the case of a single operator $S\in B(H)$, i.e. $\mathcal{S}=\{S\}$. Then $\langle\mathcal{S}\rangle =\mathbb{C}[S]$ is the algebra of all polynomials in $S$.

- In finite dimension, we always have $\mathbb{C}[S]=\{S\}^{''}$.
- In the infinite-dimensional case, there are quite a few examples of non-normal operators $S$ for which the double commutant property $\overline{\mathbb{C}[S]}^{wot}= \{S\}^{''}$ holds. I'll just mention the unilateral shift operator ([Brown-Halmos](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0213), "Algebraic properties of Toeplitz operators", Crelle 1964). See also the paper "Contractions with the bicommutant property", Proc.AMS 1985, by [Takahashi](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1985-093-01/S0002-9939-1985-0766534-7/S0002-9939-1985-0766534-7.pdf). And see also, indeed, the recent paper by [Marcoux and Mastnak](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Elwmarcou/Preprints/MM2012.pdf) for possibly non-singly-generated algebras with the bicommutant property.
- From now on, let us restrict to the case where $S$ is normal, in infinite dimension. Note that by [Fuglede's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem), the commutant of $\{S\}$ coincides with the commutant of the self-adjoint set $\{S,S^*\}$. Therefore, by [von Neumann bicommutant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_bicommutant_theorem),
  $$\{S\}^{''}=\{S,S^*\}^{''}=\overline{\mathbb{C}[S,S^*]}^{wot}$$
  is a von Neumann algebra. So $\overline{\mathbb{C}[S]}^{wot}= \{S\}^{''}$ if and only if $\overline{\mathbb{C}[S]}^{wot}$ is a $*$-algebra.
  The next key point is due to [Sarason](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-17/issue-3/Invariant-subspaces-and-unstarred-operator-algebras/pjm/1102994515.full), "Invariant subspaces and unstarred operator algebras", Pacific JM 1966 (corollary p.511): $\overline{\mathbb{C}[S]}^{wot}$ is a $*$-algebra if and only if $S$ is reductive, i.e. every closed invariant subspace $F$ of $S$ is a reducing subspace (i.e. $F^\perp$ is invariant under $S$ as well or, equivalently, $F$ is invariant under $S^*$). [In finite dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/436466/38053), $S$ is reductive if and only if $S$ is normal. Recall that the wot/sot are not metrizable in infinite dimmension (although they are metrizable on norm bounded sets when $H$ is separable): in the 1952 Proc. AMS paper "On invariant subspaces of normal operators", [Wermer](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-02/S0002-9939-1952-0048700-X/) constructed an example of reductive normal operator $S\in B(H)$ such that $S^*$ does not belong to the wot sequential closure of $\mathbb{C}[S]$, although it lies in the wot closure, and in sharp contrast with the finite-dimensional case where $S^*$ is a polynomial in $S$ for every normal operator $S$.
- Of course, every bounded (skew-)self-adjoint operator operator is reductive. So these give other examples where the bicommutant property holds. Now we finally reach what could be the simplest counterexample: **the bilateral shift**
  $$
  S:\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\longrightarrow\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\qquad  S:e_n\longmapsto e_{n+1}
  $$
  is unitary, whence normal, and not reductive as $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is $S$-invariant, but not $S^*$-invariant. Therefore
  $$\overline{\mathbb{C}[S]}^{wot}\subsetneq\{S\}^{''}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much @julien for this nice answer !

Answer (score 3):

Here is a preprint (Marcoux, Mastnak 2012) : [Non-selfadjoint double commutant theorem](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~lwmarcou/Preprints/MM2012.pdf).

I asked the authors for posting an answer here. While waiting here's the abstract of their article:

**Abstract.**
The von Neumann Double Commutant Theorem states that if $\mathcal{N}$ is a unital and selfadjoint subalgebra of the set $B(H)$ of all bounded linear operators acting on a Hilbert space $H$, and if $\mathcal{N}':=\{T \in B(H) :TN=NT \text{ for all}  N \in  \mathcal{N} \}$  denotes the commutant of
$\mathcal{N}$, then $\mathcal{N}'' = \overline{\mathcal{N}}$. In this paper, we begin the analysis of not necessarily
selfadjoint subalgebras $\mathcal{S}$ of $B(H)$ whose second commutant $\mathcal{S}''$ agrees with $\mathcal{S}$. More specically, we examine the case where $\mathcal{S}= \mathcal{D}+ \mathcal{R}$, where $\mathcal{R}$ is a bimodule over a masa $\mathcal{M}$ in $B(H)$ and $\mathcal{D}$ is a unital subalgebra of $\mathcal{M}$.

*If the authors don't respond to my call, I will take the time to browse their article in order to post here a more appropriate response.*