# If a subspace is $T$-invariant, prove that it is $T^*$-invariant.

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is as follows.

> Let $T:V \longrightarrow V$ be a normal ($T^*T=TT^*$) linear operator
>   on a space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\dim(V)<\infty$.
>   Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$.
>
> Prove that if $W$ is $T$-invariant (that is, $T(W)\subset W $) then
>   $W$ is $T^*$-invariant.

**What I've already tried:** 
I know that if $T:V \longrightarrow V$, then $\ker(T^*(V))=[T(V)]^\perp$. If this holds using the restriction $T|_W$ instead of $T$ and $W$ instead of $V$ then I can prove it, but in the end I couldn't prove that this property holds in that case, so I'm afraid that it isn't valid at all.

Comment: This is proved in the [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/436466/38053). Note that in general $W$ is $T$ invariant iff $W^\perp $ is $T^*$ invariant. So what you want to prove says that every invariant subspace of a normal operator is reducing (in finite dimension), which makes this close to a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I'd never figure it by myself. So in this case... should I close the question?

Comment: You can also answer your question, that's ok.

Comment: Hm, so should I show that this is equivalent to the question in the link you've mentioned?

Comment: Either that, or directly answer your question. Up to you. Maybe the second option is better.